# How to update YAML file without loss of comments and formatting / YAML automatic refactoring in Python

Tags: python, yaml, text-parsing, automated-refactoring

I would like to update YAML file values in Python without losing formatting and comments in Python. For example I would like to tranform

YAML file

```
value: 456                  # nice value
```

to

```
value: 6                  # nice value
```

with interface similar to

```
y = yaml.load('path')
y['value'] = 6
y.save()
```

Is there some way how to do it elegantly in Python (without writting a new YAML parsing library)?

I need systematic longterm maintainable solution - so no `regex` substitutions is okey for me since they get ugly and hardly maintainable, when you do to much of them in your code.

I haven't found any Python library which does the job. The only library I found, which is considering the feature, but is not implemented it yet, is C library `libyaml`([issue on Github](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/issues/42)). Have I missed any?

The problem might be also formulated as: do you know some automatic refactoring YAML library in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? have you ever worked with `ruamel.yaml` module?

Comment: @eshirvana Whenever I needed something like this, I wrote a parser or used regexes. But I would like to have some less clumsy solution.

Comment: @eshirvana I have never tried ruamel.yaml package. Does it do the job I need?

Comment: there are tons of libraries to parse yaml. what is wrong with pyyaml? https://pyyaml.org/

Comment: @LudvigH When you load it, edit it and save it, you don't get only the same data in the saved file. Not the same file.

Comment: I dont understand what the issue is. please explain what you tried, and why that solution was not suitable.

Comment: @LudvigH The issue is: I have a nice YAML formatted file with comments, etc. Using the ordinary YAML parsing library causes the data from it being loaded without formatting (pure dictionary structure). When you save the dictionary again, you get newly created file without the original comments, formatting, etc... These libraries can't reconstruct it, because during the parsing they don't care "how the file looked like". If you want, I can send you related `libyaml` issue from GitHub. Maybe, you will be able to understand the problem better from it.

Comment: Ah. I see. Please don't send that to me. Update the question with that information instead. :)

Comment: @LudvigH I have added the link there. :) - Do you have any idea, how to make the question more readable, so you would understand it on first reading? For me, it is quite obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) may be what you are looking for, it is a YAML parser/emitter that supports roundtrip preservation of comments:

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_data = "value: 456                  # nice value"

yaml = YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_data)
data["value"] = 6

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

---

**Output:**

```
value: 6                    # nice value
```